# Complex group by using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

I am facing a situation where I need to group-by a dataframe by a column 'ID' and also calculate the total time frame depicted for that particular ID to complete. I only want to calculate the difference between the date_open and data_closed for the particular ID with the ID count.
We only need to focus on the date open and the date closed field. So it needs to do something taking the max closing date and the min open date and subtracting the two 
The dataframe looks as follows:

```
ID      Date_Open     Date_Closed
1       01/01/2019     02/01/2019
1       07/01/2019     09/01/2019
2       10/01/2019     11/01/2019
2       13/01/2019     19/01/2019
3       10/01/2019     11/01/2019
```

The output should look like this :

```
ID     Count_of_ID     Total_Time_In_Days
1         2                8
2         2                9
3         1                1
```

How should I achieve this ?

Comment: Please demonstrate the effort of solving the issue yourself (provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) and potentially ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `GroupBy` with named_aggregation and the `min` and `max` of the dates:

```
df[['Date_Open', 'Date_Closed']] = (
    df[['Date_Open', 'Date_Closed']].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%d/%m/%Y'))
)

dfg = df.groupby('ID').agg(
    Count_of_ID=('ID','size'),
    Date_Open=('Date_Open','min'),
    Date_Closed=('Date_Closed','max')
)

dfg['Total_Time_In_Days'] = dfg['Date_Closed'].sub(dfg['Date_Open']).dt.days
dfg = dfg.drop(columns=['Date_Closed', 'Date_Open']).reset_index()
```

```
   ID  Count_of_ID  Total_Time_In_Days
0   1            2                   8
1   2            2                   9
2   3            1                   1
```

Now we have `Total_Time_In_Days` as `int`:

```
print(dfg.dtypes)

ID                    int64
Count_of_ID           int64
Total_Time_In_Days    int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how are you getting the word "days" in the last column?

Comment: That's just the way the `timedelta` is represented, if you want seconds for example, use `(dfg['Date_Closed'] - dfg['Date_Open']).dt.total_seconds()`

Comment: and to just see the number without the days or seconds, what should be done? I just want the last column to be of int type. Should I just type cast it?

Comment: Sorry I was misunderstanding you, see edit, we can get the amount of days in integer by accessing the `days` attribute with `dt.days`. @Django0602

Comment: Thank you for the edit.. Looks fine now.. One more thing.. I have ran the code on m y dataset and I am getting all the counts as 1 and the last column is only coming out to be correct where the actual count of ID is also 1. But when the count is more than 1, the days are also coming out to be wrong

Comment: Did you convert correctly to datetime with the first line. You have to make sure the date format you gave in your example is the same as in your data. Right now in my answer I assumed: `%d/%m/%Y` which is `dd/mm/yyyy`

Answer (score 1):

This can also be used:

```
df['Date_Open'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Open'], dayfirst=True)
df['Date_Closed'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Closed'], dayfirst=True)
df_grouped = df.groupby(by='ID').count()
df_grouped['Total_Time_In_Days'] = df.groupby(by='ID')['Date_Closed'].max() - df.groupby(by='ID')['Date_Open'].min()
df_grouped = df_grouped.drop(columns=['Date_Open'])
df_grouped.columns=['Count', 'Total_Time_In_Days']
print(df_grouped)


     Count  Total_Time_In_Days
ID      
1      2    8 days
2      2    9 days
3      1    1 days
```

Answer (score -1):

I'll try first to create the a column depicting how much time passed from Date_open to Date_closed for each instance of the dataframe. Like this:

```
df['Total_Time_In_Days'] = df.Date_closed - df.Date_open
```

Then you can use groupby:

```
df.groupby('id').agg({'id':'count','Total_Time_In_Days':'sum'})
```

If you need any help with the .agg function you can refer to it's official documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html).

Comment: That's not what he wants, he's looking for max(Date_closed) - min(Date_open) of each ID, not each row.